# In a UWP project how can I have design-time binding against a DependencyProperty?

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp

I'm looking for a way to use XAML Binding that binds not only to a DependencyProperty, but also can provide a design-time view.

I have this dependency property for a viewmodel object in the code behind:

```
private static DependencyProperty s_itemProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(BadgeItemViewModel), typeof(DetailPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static DependencyProperty ItemProperty
{
    get { return s_itemProperty; }
}
```

In this example binding does not find "Item" but will give me a fallback design-time view :

```
    <Grid Width="100" Margin="5,20,4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Ellipse x:Name="elipAvatar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Item.media.badge_image_lg, FallbackValue='https://untappd.akamaized.net/badges/bdg_StPatirkcs2018_lg.jpg'}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

In this example, runtime binding with x:Bind works great and I can get Intellisense access to the "Item" object in my XAML but I don't get a fallback type value and x:Bind doesn't in general support design-time data:

```
    <Grid Width="100" Margin="5,20,4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Ellipse x:Name="elipAvatar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind Item.media.badge_image_lg, TargetNullValue='https://untappd.akamaized.net/badges/bdg_StPatirkcs2018_lg.jpg'}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

Is it possible to get a compromise where I can not only access the Item viewmodel object in XAML and also provide a design-time view or at least a fallback value for the Image?

Thanks,
 Rick

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a compromise where I can not only access the Item viewmodel object in XAML and also provide a design-time view or at least a fallback value for the Image?

It seems you can not access the Item viewmodel object in XAML and also provide a design-time view or at least a fallback value for the Image in your this scenario.

{Binding} assumes, by default, that you're binding to the **DataContext** of your markup page. The **DataContext** property which is of type Object, and is also subject to change at run time. When you use the {Binding}, in design time, the Visual studio can not recognize the DataModel type, so you can not find the "Item" and its properties on the xaml. On other hand, the [FallbackValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.fallbackvalue#Windows_UI_Xaml_Data_Binding_FallbackValue) Property is for getting or setting the value to use when the binding is unable to return a value, if your binding path is correct and return a value, the **FallbackValue** will not display. You can try to rebuild your project and give an incorrect path to see the FallbackValue.

{x:Bind} does not use the DataContext as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods. If the `Item` object in your code behind, you can access it and it's properties. But the source uri is in the ViewModel code, the Visual studio still can not get the resource. Meanwhile, the **TargetNullValue** and the **FallbackValue** also are introduced in the [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension), you can look into it.

More details, please see the [{Binding} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension#property-path) and [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).